# Is the stack offset assigned to local stack variables ever reused, e.g. in case it becomes dead or goes out of scope?

Tags: c, memory-management, stack, reverse-engineering, compiler-optimization

In other words, will compilers allocate enough space in the program stack to store all variables at the deepest level of block nesting in the current function or do they look at liveness and the scope of variables too?

```
void zoo(int num) {
    if (num) {
        int a = foo();
        bar(a);
    } else {
        int b = foo();
        bar(b);
    }
}
```

For example the above code will be assigned different offsets on the stack for `a` and `b`, even though, if they were assigned only one offset (e.g. `rbp - 8`) it would have been legal too. My question is that will compilers like gcc and clang ever output assembly where multiple variables are assigned the same static offset?

Is there anything in the specifications about this?

I want to know if there is a unique mapping between source variables and the stack offsets present in a compiled assembly file.

Comment: You tagged this with C and not C++ but showed C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

There is, in general, no unique mapping between objects with automatic storage duration (“local” objects defined inside a function or block) and stack offsets. I have seen compiler-generated code reuse the same stack location for different objects, either because the use of one did not overlap the use of the other in the C code or because the compiler had moved one into a register for whatever purposes and no longer needed to use the stack location for it.

The C and C++ standards do not require implementations to implement their stack allocation in any particular way. They are free to reuse stack locations. They are also free to allocate all the stack space that might be needed<sup>1</sup> or to wait to see if particular blocks are entered or not before further allocating stack space for the objects inside those blocks.

## Note

<sup>1</sup> Implementations that support variable-length arrays generally must wait until the size of the array can be determined before allocating space for it.